# is there a way to use crop/scale as identity filters (i.e. bypassed) in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg-python to build and maintain a relatively complex filter chain, which may (but don't always) need to include scale and crop filters (possibly more than one of each).

My current code has a lot of if/then/else logic that looks at the parameters passed from the user, and then either inserts those filter nodes into the chain or not depending on the args.

The code would be much cleaner and easier to maintain if I could just leave all the possible filters in the chain, but somehow pass them arguments that made them function as identity filters -- meaning that they simply passed through the input directly to the output without actually doing anything.

Is this something that is implemented somehow in these filters?  For example, if I run a crop filter with args (x=0, y=0, h=in_h, w=in_w) this should make the output the same as the input, but it's not clear to me whether this is an actual bypass (meaning I don't spend the cycles/effort) or if we actually somehow crop the frame.

Same question applies for the scale filter: if I feed the scale filter arguments that result in the output dimensions being the same as the input dimensions, do we actually do anything to these frames?

Answer (score 1):

If the input and output parameters are identical, scale filter is a no-op however that's not the case for crop, which will end up doing a frame copy in memory.

You can use a null filter to do a bypass.

So, if your filterchain is, say, `filter1,scale,filter3,crop,filter5`, then in case of bypass, you would declare `filter1,null,filter3,null,filter5`.

Comment: OK, this is what I was asking.. I guess I got half the answer I wanted ;)
I was hoping I could keep the chain itself the same, but to avoid the frame copy for crop it sounds like that's not going to happen.  Is it worth asking whoever maintains the crop filter to implement a no-op in case the input/output parameters are the same?

Comment: Not worth the effort. Even with 4K frames cropped to FullHD, the filter is fast enough that avg crop time per frame still registers as 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically planing to move those `if/else` decisions from your parameter-generating code into the `ffmpeg` executable. This is not a good idea.

One of the reasons is, that `libav` (correctly) has no requirement of every frame in a stream being of the same size - so the decision to crop has to be taken for every frame, while in the parameter-generating code it has to be made only once.

A few words concerning my assumption of correctness: `ffmpeg` is broadly used in the broadcast industry - and there a sequence of SD/HD/UHD content (old film, TV series, new cinematic content) is quite normal and expected to be correctly procesed.

Comment: I don't think I explained it well.  I want to use ffmpeg with a consistent filter complex, but I'm *not* moving the decisions into the ffmpeg executable.  I want to know if there are ways to (implicitly or explicitly) avoid the overhead of executing a scale or crop filter based on the arguments that are passed.

Comment: You explained well allright, but again: The scale/crop filter has to decide on every single frame, the parameter-generating python script only once. So the resource usage of doing it in python is `O(1)` while in the filter it is at least `O(n)` for n frames processed - it can be higher if e.g. you use special cases like interlacing with h.264.